# Fixed menubar overlaps the linked content on the same page

Tags: html, css, anchor, css-position

I've got a news page where I echo out the news from my MYSQL database, and on the right site of the page i echo out the titles which is a anchor link to that section of the page.

Like if there is a news called "Hey". Then if you press "Hey" you will be moved there. . That works just fine. The problem is that the page has a menu that is position fixed. When I press "hey" it works fine, it's just that the fixed menu overlaps some of the content.

So I'd like to go to that anchor tag, but minus the size of the menu.

No real reason to post the code as that really wont explain it, but the thing is that you get linked to the anchor tag, it's just that the fixed menu overlaps it. I saw something about adding a class to the  tag and have that to position relative and margin-top on minus the height of the menu. But that just moves the links.

Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 0):

Anything with position: fixed is taken out of the normal content flow and, therefore, does not take up space on the page. If I understand you correctly, you want your menu (which is position: fixed) to take up space on the page but to remain floating. To accommodate this, you will need to do one of two things:

1. If you are OK with simply making room for the menu down the entire vertical length of the page, just add a margin-right to the entire page that is the width (or slightly wider) than the menu.
2. If you want to have each article have a space in the upper-right of it's content just big enough for the menu and for the content to flow around it, create a div that is the same size as the menu before each article and give it float: right.

Your question was somewhat vague as to the outcome that you were looking for and without the code I cannot give specifics. I hope this gives a general guide as to where to go.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. But thanks anyways. My menu has a very low opacity so you can see through it. And when you press the a anchor you get linked to an article on the same page, and the menus 70 pxs overlaps that. So I'd like to get linked to the same page, but 70pxs higher up.